# how to popup a small window which 1 text box with date picker & select drop down list and ok, close button

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

The following code popping up but date picker not working
my HTML coding as follows

```
<a id="popuplink" href="#">Click Me</a>
<div id="popup">
<div id="content">
<input id="date" type="text"/>
<select id="data_load_mode">
    <option value="replace">Replace</option>
    <option value="merge">Merge</option>
    <option value="append">Append</option>
</select>
<input id="date_subbmit" class="btn1" type="button" value="OK">
<input id="date_cancel" class="btn1" type="button" value="Cancel">
 </div>       
 </div>
```

my jQuery as follows

```
(function(){
    $('#popuplink').click(function(){       
        $('#popup').show("slow");
    });
    $('#popupclose').click(function(){
        var text=$('#date').val();
        alert(text);
        $('#popup').hide("slow");
    });
    $(#date).datepick();
});
```

my CSS

```
#popup
{
display:none;
position: fixed;
width:250px;
height: 150px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left:-155px;
margin-top:-110px;
border:5px solid red;
background-color:#DEDFDE;
padding:30px;
z-index:102;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:10pt;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius:20px;
font-weight:bold;
 }
```

Comment: Check this line `$(#date).datepick()` it must be like this `$('#date').datepick()`. You have missed out the quotes.

Comment: i have added the quotes

Comment: Try this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/uo2yy55y/
Here I have used `datepicker()`